A genius Margonon!
To solve the puzzle below, the standard rules of a fill-a-pix (or mosaic) apply:

Paint the squares around each clue black so that the number of painted squares, including the square with the clue, matches the value of the clue.
Additional note: every clue that should be a 0, 3, 6 or 9, is given.

The final answer is the location where this puzzle originated.

text version:
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ,3, ,3, ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
 ,3, , , ,3,3,3,3, ,6, ,6, ,3, , , , ,3,3,3,3,3, 
3, ,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, , , ,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, ,3
 , , , , , ,6,6,6,6,6,6,6, , , , , ,3,3,3, , , , 
3,3,3,3, , ,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, , , ,3,3, , , , , ,6, 
 , , , ,6, ,6,6,6,6,6,6,6, , , , , ,3, , , , ,6,3
3, , ,6, ,6, , , ,6,6, , , ,6,6, , , ,7,7, , ,3, 
 ,3, , , , ,8, , ,9,9, , , ,9,9, , , ,7, , , , ,0
0,0, , , , , , , , , , , , , ,6, , , , , , ,0,0,0
 , ,0,0, , ,3,3,3, ,6, , ,6, ,3,3,3, , ,0,0, , , 
3, ,3,3,3, , ,0,0, , , , , , ,0, , ,3,3,3,3, , , 
 , ,6,6, ,3, , , , ,6, , ,6, , , , , , ,6,6, , ,6
 ,6,6,6, ,3, , , , , ,6,6, , ,2,2, , , ,6,6,6,6, 


This puzzle originated in the:

 CAVE OF WONDERS

Because the final image hidden here is:

 A magic lamp!



 Plus this phrase can be extracted from the final solved state...

A few notes on the solution path... It's fairly straightforward just using standard fill-a-pix/mosaic logic to get to a state like this:

 

At this point we need to start using the rule where all 0s, 3s, 6s and 9s have been given in the grid... For example, here marked in red are a set of cells which cannot be left blank, otherwise they will force one of these values in itself or a nearby square:

 

 ...which leads us to this state:



We can keep repeating this process, using the opposite situation too - some cells marked with blue which if shaded would break this no more 0/3/6/9 values rule:

 

 From here it's a short series of steps to the final solved state:



 Note the appropriateness of the title - 'genius' being a reference to 'genies', since this is an image of a magic lamp, which contains a genie.

How do we extract the final answer?

 The question marks in the side and top panels suggest that this puzzle is also the solved state of a nonogram, where numbers in these areas represent all runs of shaded cells in the grid. Let's fill in these numbers, as if solving a reverse nonogram (as per the 'margonon' - 'nonogram' backwards - in the title):



 If we now sum the numbers in each row of the side-panel (note the arrow in the original image showing that this part of the puzzle has an importance which we have not yet used) to see how many squares are shaded in each row, we produce the numbers 3-1-22-5-15-6-23-15-14-4-5-18-19. Converting these to letters, we produce the phrase CAVE OF WONDERS. This is the location in the film Aladdin where the genie's lamp can be found, so everything ties together.


Well done, you've got everything!

@Lezzzup Nice work on altering that image to fit the "Cave of Wonders" numbers and still have it look like a magic lamp. And great thorough answer, as usual, Stiv

@JLee, thanks! It took some time to find a suitable couple of words to create an image from it, haha. Especially the A-C and the letters P-Z are tough.
